# How can I extract images in their native/maximum resolution from a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, images

How would one go about extracting images in their native/maximum resolution from a PDF file?

I have been trying different methods of exporting images/screenshots and end up with huge bloated files that are still lower detail than the PDF file.

Comment: Find the original document, rather than try and de-compress a compressed image in a compressed document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract images in PDF without affecting the resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/193485/extract-images-in-pdf-without-affecting-the-resolution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract images from a pdf file with [`pdfimages`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages) program that is a part of the [Poppler library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) available as `poppler-utils` package on many Linux based OS. It is even available on [Windows](https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/). See the [man page for `pdfimages`](https://www.mankier.com/1/pdfimages) for available options.

This command lists the images embedded in a PDF file:

```
pdfimages -list sample.pdf
```

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    4960  7008  gray    1   1  jbig2  no         6  0   600   600  132K 3.1%
   2     1 image    4960  7008  gray    1   1  jbig2  no        11  0   600   600 40.4K 1.0%
   3     2 image    4960  7008  gray    1   1  jbig2  no        15  0   600   600 26.3K 0.6%
```

To extract the images:

```
pdfimages -j -png sample.pdf sample
```

This will extract any JPEG images in original JPEG format and the others will default to lossless PNG format, so you'll end up with files like this:

```
sample-000.jpg
sample-001.jpg
sample-002.png
sample-003.png
```

In a rare case that you can’t install any software, you might want to try an online service like [pdf extract tool](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/extract.aspx).

Comment: So Poppler is up to version 23 now, but the Windows version is still at 0.68? Does that sound right?